# string with prefix * in Go language

Tags: string, go

Consider a piece of Go code:

`var infile *string = flag.String("i", "infile", "File contains values for sorting")`

I wonder what does the *string mean in Go?

Comment: You should really read at least some introductory material about the language before asking questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The * prefix means that the variable is a pointer to a string rather than the value of the string. See http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values and http://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types.

Basically a pointer is a memory reference to a value somewhere.